# How do I use an Avro type in another Avro type, without defining it again?

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I have defined an Avro type called `"some.package.SourceMetadata"` in a json file called `commonSourceMetadata.avsc`:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SourceMetadata",
  "namespace": "some.package",
  "fields": [..]
}
```

and I am trying to use it in another avsc file, using an `imports` keyword I found in `Apache Avro 1.7.3`:

```
  "imports": ["commonSourceMetadata.avsc"],
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "sourceMetadata",
      "type": "some.package.SourceMetadata"
    },
```

I also tried:

```
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "sourceMetadata",
      "imports": ["commonSourceMetadata.avsc"],
      "type": "some.package.SourceMetadata"
    },
```

The `Apache Avro` version is `1.9`.

Still I get:

```
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: "some.package.SourceMetadata" is not a defined name. The type of the "sourceMetadata" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1637)
```

It is also clear to me that it does not take into account `imports` or `import` because I tried to import an inexistent file and no complains there.

How can i make it a `defined name`?

We are using Scala, SBT and the AvroHugger plugin to generate Scala case classes from the avsc Avro type definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Avro **schema format** (in JSON, usually with the `.avsc` extension)  is defined by the [specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.2/spec.html).

The Avro **IDL format** is a different, non-JSON [syntax](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.2/idl.html#imports), designed to be familiar for developers writing RPC protocols.

The `import` keyword is only supported in IDL.  This is intentional, since sharing a schema (JSON) shouldn't require also sharing a filesystem.

It looks AvroHugger provides two ways to do what you want:

1. Simply include all `avsc` files when generating your case classes and AvroHugger [should be able to resolve](https://github.com/julianpeeters/avrohugger#avrohugger-filesorter) the names, or
2. Use the IDL format (also supported by AvroHugger) which permits the `import` keyword.

Comment: That is a great answer, but it's not that clear to me where the sort method should be called in the compiling lifecycle and how to hook in the generation phase. With maven avro support/plugin, it is a matter of configuring imports, a clear thing, here i am not sure where sorting can be plugged and how (except for calling a sortFiles)

Comment: I did include all the avsc files but it did not resolve them..I understand what you're saying about their sorter, but I am not sure it is automatically being used, and if not, what would be the way I could use it without forking the AvroHugger plugin..